# Is it possible to treat the "end of the data reached while reading header rows" warning as an error?

Tags: ssis, warnings

We've found that in some situations, when SSIS is given an invalid data file, it will not produce an error but will instead give a warning like:

```
Warning: The end of the data file was reached while reading header rows. 
Make sure the header row delimiter and the number of header rows to skip are correct.
```

This happens, as would be expected, when there is anything wrong with the headers, whether it's an incorrect delimiter or if they're missing entirely (e.g. an empty file).

I can't understand why SSIS would treat this as just a warning and not an error - the input is clearly not in the format we've defined. In any case, is it possible to force SSIS to produce an error instead of a warning in these cases? Otherwise, how would we catch data feeds that are incorrect in this way?